# WPF Binding StringFormat

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a textblock bound to an integer. What I want is to show (+25) for positive number and (-25) for a negative one.
So far i have been able to do it separately with the following xaml:

```
  StringFormat={}({0})}  // shows binding in a bracket
  StringFormat=+#;-#;0   // shows the sign
```

What would the xaml for the combined formatting be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringFormat="({0:+#;-#;0})"` did work for me.